# How to parse DXF hatch by means of dxflib

Tags: c++, c, dxf, dxflib

I am using [dxflib](http://www.qcad.org/en/what-is-dxflib) in order to parse DXF files. I have implemented the class `DL_CreationAdapter`

```
class EntityHandler : public DL_CreationAdapter
{
public:

    /** Called for every hatch entity. */
    void addHatch(const DL_HatchData& data);

    /** Called for every hatch loop. */
    void addHatchLoop(const DL_HatchLoopData& data);

    /** Called for every hatch edge entity. */
    void addHatchEdge(const DL_HatchEdgeData& data);

};
```

But I have a problem while parsing entities of type hatch. That is, I am not able to find the data related to *rounded paths*.

Considering for example the following DXF image:

[image]

For each `DL_HatchEdgeData` I receive `DL_HatchEdgeData.type` equals to 0 and a list of vertices, so that I am able to build a path like the following one:

[image]

Please note the difference between the two images.

Where can I find some information about the fact that some 
conjunctions of my path are *rounded*?